# window.opener issue with window.open() when replacing a window

Tags: javascript, window.opener

I have a web application where page #1 opens a popup window using

```
window.open(myUrl, "fixedApplicationTargetId", "");
```

Then page #2 overwrites the same popup window with a call to window.open using **the same target** value

```
window.open(anotherUrl, "fixedApplicationTargetId", "");
```

At this point the content of the popup originally created by page #1 shows the new content created by page #2. So far so good with any browser.

Then the popup itself detects who last opened the popup and updated the content using window.opener. Prior to calling window.open both page #1 and page #2 create a global variable globalPageId and assign a unique number each. The popup checks the value of window.opener.globalPageId and detects which window last updated the popup content.

This is where things fall apart: the above works fine with chrome and firefox that update window.opener in the popup each time the content is updated with window.open. Instead, IE and opera always point the popup window.opener to the first window that used window.open.

**Any suggestion, in a context where multiple pages call window.open on the same target, how to detect from the popup itself which window last opened the window?**

Answer (score 1):

[window.opener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.opener) is supposed to be read-write (except in Internet Explorer 3), so you could set it to the appropriate window yourself. Some browsers, however, restrict this operation and only allow setting `opener` to `null` to [prevent security issues](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=184618).

An alternate solution would be to use a custom property instead of `opener`. You could set it by hand:

```
window.open(myUrl, "fixedApplicationTargetId", "").realOpener = window;
```

Then use `window.realOpener.globalPageId` instead of `window.opener.globalPageId` in the rest of your code.

Comment: Maybe getting there... at least closer...

I tried 

`(popupWin = window.open(myUrl, fixedTarget, options)).myOpener = window;`

and it works in chrome, but IE still fails to assign myOpener properly.
It should be a timing issue, it works in IE with


`popupWin = window.open(myUrl, fixedTarget, options));`
`setTimeout("popupWin.myOpener = window;", 1000);`

Is there a way to get notified of the completed load of the popup so that I perform the the proper assignement (obviously I cant use the opener in the popup since this is the starting issue)?
I'd hate to rely on setTimeout...

Comment: @Paolo, if you don't mind the delay, you can try handling the `load` event of the popup. However, I'm not sure `setTimeout()` is an issue here, maybe control just has to leave the current function. Does `setTimeout(function() { popupWin.myOpener = window; }, 4);` give the same result?

Comment: Tried to bring the timeout down to 10ms and it did not work anymore. I'm afraid setTimeout is an issue. Not sure what you mean with handling the load event of the popup... I can't obviously do that from the popup itself since I won't have access to the opener (the issue we are discussing in the first place), unless I start a periodic timeout from the opener to check readystate of the client... sounds very artificial...

Comment: @Paolo, I meant handling the `load` event of the popup from the opener window. Something like `popupWin = window.open(myUrl, fixedTarget, options); popupWin.onload = function() { popupWin.myOpener = window; };`.

Comment: Thanks for your help... that does not work. I guess if I cant access the popup win to set a variable then I cant access it to set the onload event either... I'll probably give up on this one and leave it as one of the many IE incompatibilities...

Comment: I tried window.open(..).myProperty = window, but it not works for me. myProperty always remains `undefined' in IE.9